# Postgress Python Robot Framework SyntaxError: "INSERT has more expressions than target columns"

Tags: python, postgresql, robotframework

I am new to all things programming. That being said, I am not completely sure what type of information would help solve my problem. So, here we go:

I have this query:

```
begin;
    set transaction read write;
    alter database SOMETHING set default_transaction_read_only = off;
INSERT INTO plans(title, duration, price, created_at, updated_at)
VALUES ('Plano Platinum', 12, 60, now(),now());
commit;
```

I have this Python code (I don't really know Python):

[Python code for query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk7SP.png)

I am using Robot Framework to create automated tests. The error I keep getting is the following:

> SyntaxError: INSERT has more expressions than target columns LINE 1:
> ..., updated_at)values ('Plano Platinum',12,60,00,now(),now());
> ^

But the columns and values match, right? So I am not sure what is it that I am doing wrong.

Comment: 1) Do not use images for textual information. Copy and paste the code as text to your question. 2) Do not use `format` to build the query, that is the path to SQL injection. 3) Pretty sure `'{}'` is your issue. 4) What Python library are you using for database access?

Comment: Thanks for the tips and help! I am using Python 3.9.2

Comment: I tried to remove the single quotes and I got another error. I think single quotes are there to sinalize it is a String, right? I put it back and I got the firts mistake back again. My issue is this: why I am getting two zeros after "60"? Where does it come from? The column for PRICE is a numeric value; does that say something?

Comment: Again, what Python library(not Python version) are you using to connect to the database? For instance `psycopg2`. Also replace the Python code image with text. `60,00` is coming from `plan['duration']` so you need to find out where/how that is creating the value.